# Screenshot robot only captures a black screen on Debian

Tags: java, linux, debian, openjdk-11

I am creating a screen capture using `java.awt.Robot` under Linux with OpenJDK 11. The result on Linux is a whole black image. The same code works on Ubuntu and Windows (using another file path of course).

Any clue?

```java
public void captureScreen() throws AWTException {
    Robot robot = new Robot(GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice());
    BufferedImage screen = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
    try {
        ImageIO.write(screen, "jpg", new File("/tmp/screenshot.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

> **UPDATE:**
>   The the cause of the problem lies in the combination of OpenJDK and Wayland.
>   With Oracle JDK/JRE (13.0.1) everything works fine.

Comment: Works fine for me (OpenJDK 11.0.4 2019-07-16 on Ubuntu 18.04).

Comment: That's odd, I'm using OpenJDK 11.0.5 2019-10-15 on Debian 10 (Buster). So the problem could be related to the desktop environment?

Comment: I've tried on xubuntu, i.e., XFCE. I'd doubt that the desktop environment makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I suspected AppArmor as possible cause and uninstalled it, but it did not change anything.

Comment: #1 What do you mean with works in linux but not in ubuntu? #2 Could you try with some of these apps https://alternativeto.net/software/snagit/?platform=linux in order to discard or verify some issue or misconfiguration at o.s level?

Comment: #1 it works on Ubuntu 18.04 but it does not work on a fresh installation of the latest Debian (10 aka Buster) #2 i'll give it a try this saturday - but I think the problem is rather Java related, as the default screenshot app works as expected.

Comment: Is it possible for some reason you have multiple graphic devices and Java is seeing one which isnt the "default"? Maybe try screenshots on all of `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()`

Comment: No, I've got only one integrated Intel GPU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using wayland instead of XOrg this may be causing the problem as it is less stable with Java interfaces for graphics operations.

Edit: This bug has now been fixed (see OP)

Comment: You're perfectly right! I worked as expected as soon as is switched to Gnome on xorg. So the problem is definetly Wayland related, I opened an issue on their project site https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/wayland/wayland/issues/130 Thanks a lot!